# Add specific employee to a page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

We have created many pages in Wordpress and want to add an employee (name, phone, email etc.) to every page as responsible contact person. Now we want to add every contact person once in the backend and choose the right person in the page.

We also use Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) and could add a Field for adding the data, but it could be difficult if the employee gets a new phone number for example.

Has anyone an idea how to solve it in wordpress?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My proposition is:

1. Add custom post type named "Employees" to your WordPress.
2. Add custom fields (based on ACF) for contact data and assign them to mentioned post type.
3. Add [post object](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/post-object/) field to your pages and assign employees post type to this field.

And it's done! Now you can assign a specific employee to your page as a post object and display data from it, [like this.](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/post-object/#template-usage)